# Unnecessary condition in Rudin's theorem 7.9?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $f_{n}$ ($n=1,2,3,...$) and $f$ be functions defined on a set $E$.

The theorem states

> Suppose $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_{n}(x)=f(x) \quad (x \in E).$$ Put $$M_{n}=\sup_{x \in E} \mid f_{n}(x)-f(x) \mid.$$ Then $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $E$ if and only if $M_{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I don't understand why we need to assume pointwise convergence. Isn't convergence of the supremum simply equivalent to uniform convergence?

Comment: State the theorem without referencing $f(x)$. Can you?

Comment: You are correct that convergence in the sup norm will imply pointwise convergence; therefore, you could have just supposed that $f_n, f$ are functions. However, is this the statement of the theorem?  I don't have a copy of Rudin in front of me.. but wouldn't the proof be: "This is the definition of uniform convergence."

Comment: I do not give a downvote, but who are $f$, $f_n$ and $E$? you must specify, edit your question with all the hypotheses. Not everyone has the Rudin book.

Comment: Well, you could prove that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly Cauchy and never refer to the limit function $f$. However, in practice, the criterion in the theorem is the way we usually argue uniform convergence in concrete cases.

Comment: @ZacharySelk can't we just say that the sequence is uniformly convergent?

Comment: @Tom you are right, Rudin didn't give any proof of that because it's almost the definition of uniform convergence, which to me makes it even weirder that he assumed pointwise convergence.

Comment: @JohnMartin I edited the question, sorry.

Comment: Rudin is the worst teacher ever, that's why everyday people ask some precision about his books.

Comment: @user1952009 I agree with you, that is, it is fine for collecting useful results, but for the explanation leaves something to be desired. Similarly for the book Functional Analysis.

Comment: @JohnMartin yes, they are good books for teachers, not for students

Answer (score 2):

My take is this is a reflection of how you actually prove a sequence converges uniformly to some function. You of course need to find the pointwise limit first since that is the only candidate.

Comment: Thanks. That may be true, but just to clarify: uniform convergence IS equivalent to convergence of supremum (to 0, of course), right?

Comment: yes! But you must compute some estimate for $f$ first.

Comment: @qbert: It's not necessarily true that you need a candidate limit for a sequence -- this is one reason the Cauchy criteria is so nice. However, often one wants to find the candidate!

Comment: it is if you are using this formulation of uniform convergence no? Anyway, point taken

Comment: @qbert: Uniform convergence is equivalent to uniformly Cauchy as long as the codomain is a complete metric space, which may or may not be satisfied here (though I assume the codomain here is $\mathbb{R}$). Otherwise, if the codomain is not complete, then you do need a candidate limit!